# How to access Blob storage from an App Service as a DIR

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use Azure Blob Storage with my App Service.

I have followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage) and although it created the folder on my app service it did not sync the files I added to it.

Is this the expected behavior of Azure Blob storage and App Services?

I have also taken a look at [the blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) tutorial but I do not think this is meant for App Service as it requires installing of packages each time it is deployed.

Any help here would be great.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue. The files appeared in the mounted folder almost immediately after uploading to the storage account.

Comment: This is strange becuase when I add it via the following steps or do it via the GUI the folder appares and it says its linked but when I upload a file to it via the GUI or via the CMD in ubuntu the files do not appare or sync. Could there be a step I am missing here like file permissons or user access roles? @mmking

Comment: @mmking stange its all just started working with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

The above toutrials do work it was just being buggy on my machine.

Following on from this Azure Blobs are changing the Write permissions in [Feb 2020](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/BringYourOwnStorage/mounting_azure_blob.md) so this will be something to watch out for if tyring this method.

Also this can be set up in the App Service GUI under "configuration -> path mappings".

Hope this helps anyone else that gets stuck.